# Excel - Comparing a date to a number of date range duration and if within a date range a yes or no result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

My current formula: `=IF(AND((A4>=F4:F19),(A4<=G4:G19)),"Yes","No")`

The formula appears right but it only works if the lookup date is on the same row as dates it matches. So something is obviously wrong. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that may work for you in `B4` could be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(F$4:F$19,"<="&A4,G$4:G$19,">="&A4),"Yes","No")
```

Drag down.

Comment: Thanks man this is exactly what i wanted appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So this works:

[image]

Your version does not look at all the values in F4 to F19, which is why I use match().

Edit: you have now changed to dates, so I will let you edit the formula to suit, but the logic is there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy way to do it:

```
A           B           F           G
Lookup Date Yes or No   Start Date  End Date
15/03/2019  No          27/03/2019  21/03/2019
18/12/2020  No          24/03/2019  24/03/2019
13/09/2020  Yes         10/09/2020  14/09/2020
```

Using the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(G2<A2,A2<F2),"No", "Yes")
```

The mathematical condition for out of range is *(endDate < date) OR (date < startDate)*

[image]

the idea was taken from this [post](https://chandoo.org/wp/date-overlap-formulas/). For comparing the lookup value against all possible date ranges, the formula can be updated like this:

```
=IF(MIN(($G$2:$G$4<A2) + (A2<$F$2:$F$4))>0,"No", "Yes")
```